# Using KnockoutJs templates with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js

I would like to end up with the following HTML in the DOM using jQuery and KnockoutJs templates:

```
<div class="messageToAndFromOtherMember" id="13">
    <span>the message</span> 
    <span>2012-12-02 14:05:45.0</span> 
</div>
```

I have started writing my KO template as follows:

```
<div class="messageToAndFromOtherMember"  data-bind="attr:{ id: messageId}">
    <span data-bind="text: message"></span> 
    <span data-bind="text: sendDateFmted"></span> 
</div>
```

Upon a successful ajax request, the following js is executed:

```
var messageViewModel = {
         message: response.message, 
         sendDateFmted: response.sendDateFmted, 
         messageId: response.messageId
     };
ko.applyBindings(messageViewModel);
```

Now I am not sure how and where to actually do the binding: since my message does not exist before the ajax request is complete and I can have as several messages...

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

**EDIT 1**: I have added this to the html page:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'message-template', data: messageViewModel }"></div>
```

I now get the following js error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError:
>   $messageViewModel is not defined; Bindings value: template: { name:
>   'message-template', data: messageViewModel }

**EDIT 2**: I have altered my code as follows:

```
var messageViewModel = {
    data: ko.observable({   
        message: response.message, 
        sendDateFmted: response.sendDateFmted, 
        messageId: response.messageId
    })
     };

$("<div>",{
    class:"messageToAndFromOtherMember"
}).data("bind", "template: { name: 'message-template', data: data }").appendTo("#messagesToAndFromOtherMember");

ko.applyBindings(messageViewModel);
```

Please note that I am need to be able to add the element **from jQuery** in order to be able to add one message then another and so on. However, the above jQuery code does not work and I don't see any such thing as **data-bind** in the DOM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var messageViewModel = {
    message: ko.observable(), 
    sendDateFmted: ko.observable(), 
    messageId: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(messageViewModel);
```

When the data arrives from the server:

```
messageViewModel.message(response.message);
messageViewModel.sendDateFmted(response.sendDateFmted);
messageViewModel.messageId(response.messageId);
```

With the mapping plugin, you could do something like this instead:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(response, messageViewModel);
```

---

You really don't need templates, if you are not going to use it in multiple places. It is simpler without templates. Look at http://jsfiddle.net/3BuHR/

If you are sure you need templates, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxhm5/

---

You seem to be using knockout just for it's templating functionality. KO can do much more.

I would instead let KO handle the DOM-creation based on `observableArray`'s. When the array is modified, the DOM will be updated automatically.

```
var viewModel = {
    messages: ko.observableArray(),
};

function Message(data) {
    data = data || {};
    this.message = ko.observable(data.message);
    this.sendDateFmted = ko.observable(data.sendDateFmted);
    this.messageId = ko.observable(data.messageId);
}
```

```html
<div class="message-list" data-bind="foreach: messages">
    <div class="messageToAndFromOtherMember"  data-bind="attr:{ id: messageId}">
        <span data-bind="text: message"></span> 
        <span data-bind="text: sendDateFmted"></span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And then when data arrives from the server:

```
viewModel.messages.push(new Message(response));
```

KO will track insertions, deletions, reorderings, and update the DOM for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/v5sdf/

Comment: Hello Markus! I just wanted to start simple and not rely on the mapping plugin to begin with. I have edited my post and I would be very grateful if you could advise what syntax to use in order to make my sample work.

Comment: thanks Markus: I almost got it working: the only issue left is that I need to be able to generate the `<div data-bind= ...` from jQuery. I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you bind your template, and also, please read documentation how templating works [Knockout Tempate dinding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

I've created some example how knockout templates are work, so here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/LqY6J/)

First of all you should initialize your template like this:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/html">
    <div class="messageToAndFromOtherMember"  data-bind="attr:{ id: messageId}">
      <span data-bind="text: message"></span> 
      <span data-bind="text: sendDateFmted"></span> 
    </div>
<script>
```

Where is `id='myTmpl'` is your template's name and to call it you should do the following:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'myTmpl', foreach: $data}" ></div>
```

Here is updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/FwWDp/)

**EDIT:**

Also, I've created example for you how to use foreach + template if you will have array of your messages, [HERE IS THE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/pkysylevych/FwWDp/1/)

Comment: Thanks Pavlo! My question was: where do place the `<div data-bind="tamplate: {name: 'myTmpl', foreach: $data}" ></div>` snippet of code? In the Html page or do I generate it with jquery especially bearing in mind that the above snippet might be use several times!

Comment: You should call it in the Html page

Comment: Hi Pavlo: I don't really need the foreach because elements come from the server one at at time. What is the correct syntax that takes this into account?

Comment: I have updated my question: I need to be able to generate the `<div data-bind ...` dynamically from jQuery. Do you see my point?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I needed in order to dynamically generate the div from jQuery:

```
$("<div/>", {
  class: "messageToAndFromOtherMember",
  "data-bind": "template: { name: 'message-template', data: data }"
})
.appendTo("#messageToAndFromOtherMember");
```

Thanks a lot for your input Markus and Pavlo! I'll definitely use your tips Markus.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I still like the syntax better :)